# Cisco SG-350 Switch and Fortigate Firewall Configuration

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, firewall

I'm not what you would call a Network Engineer, but right now i have a (somewhat) complex network problem that i have to solve. I must configure a SG-35028p cisco switch and a fortigate 60f firewall to give internet access (kinda in a router on a stick fashion if you ask me).

Right now i haven't been able to achieve the objectives that the attached image shows because i'm not really sure why my vlans do not have internet access, or how to correctly configure a vlan for that matter.

Things that i have tried:

- Call eigrp on Switch:Didn't work. Command not recognized.
- Static routing on Switch: Didn't work, maybe i did it wrong.

[image: Current configuration]

EDIT: I'll add my current switch configuration to clarify the state of the setup:

```
-vlan database
-vlan 10,20,30,40,66,77
-exit

-ip dhcp server
-ip dhcp pool network EA_POOL
-address low 192.168.40.10 high 192.168.40.15 255.255.255.0
-exit

-ip dhcp pool network Main_Pool
-address low 192.168.1.10 high 192.168.1.19 255.255.255.0
-default-router 192.168.1.1
-dns-server 192.168.1.1
-exit

-ip dhcp pool network Testing_POOL
-address low 192.168.20.10 high 192.168.20.20 255.255.255.0
-exit

-ip dhcp pool network Production_POOL
-address low 192.168.30.10 high 192.168.30.20 255.255.255.0
-exit

-ip dhcp pool network Development_POOL
-address low 192.168.10.10 high 192.168.10.20 255.255.255.0
-exit

-ip dhcp information option
-bonjour interface range vlan 1
-qos advanced
-line console
-no autobaud
-exit

-ip name-server  192.168.2.99
    -ip telnet server
-!
-interface vlan 1
    -ip address 192.168.2.210 255.255.255.0
    -no ip address dhcp
-!
-interface vlan 10
    -name Development_VLAN
    -ip address 192.168.10.10 255.255.255.0
-!
-interface vlan 20
    -name Testing_VLAN
    -ip address 192.168.20.10 255.255.255.0
-!
-interface vlan 30
    -name Production_VLAN
    -ip address 192.168.30.10 255.255.255.0
-!
-interface vlan 40
    -name EA_VLAN
    -ip address 192.168.40.10 255.255.255.0
-!
-interface vlan 66
    -name unused-ports
    -shutdown
-!
-interface vlan 77
    -name OUTGOING
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet3
    -switchport access vlan 10
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet4
    -switchport access vlan 10
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet5
    -switchport access vlan 10
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet6
    -switchport access vlan 10
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet7
    -switchport access vlan 10
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet8
    -switchport access vlan 20
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet9
    -switchport access vlan 20
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet10
    -switchport access vlan 30
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet11
    -switchport access vlan 30
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet12
    -switchport access vlan 40
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet13
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet14
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet15
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet16
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet17
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet18
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet19
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet20
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet21
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet22
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet23
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet24
    -switchport access vlan 66
-!
-interface GigabitEthernet26
    -no switchport
    -switchport access vlan 77
-!
-exit
-ip default-gateway 192.168.2.99
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad, and it lacks details, such as the network device configurations. With a layer-3 switch, you should do the LAN routing on the switch and simply have a routed link to the firewall. Please edit your question to include the network device configurations.

Comment: What else should i clarify? The firewall configuration is already on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fortigate requires routes to the networks behind the SG 350. (Make sure routing has been activated on the 350, but I think it's by default.)

Since the 350 doesn't seem to support any routing protocol you'll need to set up static routes on the Fortigate.

In the GUI, static routes are in *Network -> Static Routes*. If you're not using those addresses anywhere else but the Fortigate or the 350, a single entry `192.168.0.0/16 -> 192.168.2.210` on Internal should do, with a Distance of 50 e.g., so you could still route single subnets elsewhere (with a lower Distance).

Note that your setup doesn't use a router-on-a-stick since you route at the "core" 350 (at least looks like that).

If you used the 350 as L2 only and trunked all VLANs to the Fortigate, that would be considered a router-on-a-stick.

Comment: Thank you for your help! With routing protocol you mean OSPF and EIRPG don't you? If that's the case you are probably correct (just checked). Anyways, do you have an example of how to configure the Fortinet routes? I'm pretty confused as if i should configure a new interface for vlans or i can use an already existing interface, and so on.

I'm kinda unsure if my switch configuration is right too.

Comment: Yes, OSPF and the like (there are several others). I'm adding the route setup to the answer. Since you seem to be routing everything private on the 350, you don't have to trunk the VLANs to the Fortigate. It doesn't require additional subinterfaces either.

Comment: Thanks, you were right! It was a static route problem. The trouble arised because i configured the gateways with an ip higher than the interface ip.

Answer (score 0):

If your using fortigate firewall as core or perimeter devices and Cisco SG300 as distribution switch in your setup then you can accomplish this task by creating sub interface on fortigate firewall

**Configure SG300 switch to Fortigate  firewall with trunk link allowing all vlans**

And configuration public ip of isp on outside interface of fortigate and configure default route in fortinet firewall pointing towards isp gateway

And now in SG300 switch create all vlans which were created in fortigate  subinterface  . Now create access ports in SG300 switch for desktops ,and server connetivity.

Then after create outbound policy in perimeter firewall for internet access

`source interface : Lan destination interface : Outside facing interface source address : LAN POOL NETWORK Destination address : ANY servies: ports allowed as per your requirements action : ALLOWED Security profiles: ON`

*Then create inbound policy in firewall if your are having application hosted in your local lan and wants to access from internet*

`Creaat VIP object as Publi ip mapping with " Object name " WEB SERVER = Publicip mapped with application hosted private ip`

**inbound policy**

`source interface : outside interface destination interface : LAN SOURCE ADDRESS : any destination address : WEB SERVER /*As per vip created above */ services : as per application requirement mostly "https"   security profiles : on action : allowed`

**Create implicit deny policy at bottom \ *this policy is used to deny non matching traffic and to monitoring unwanted traffic on firewall**

`Source interface : any destination interface :ANY Source address : any destination address : any services ports :  any action : deny`

**Setup diagram**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!. Just as you said, i'm trying to use a fortigate 60f as a "core" and a sg350 as "distribution". Do you have an example of how to create a subinterface on the fortigate, and an example of a trunk port configuration for all vlans on sg350? i haven't been able to do what you suggested.

Comment: Please refer above pasted link for steps to fallow to configure subinterface Configuration on fortigate firewall

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link for configuration of subinterface or router on stick configuration on fortigate firewall

**https://youtu.be/bIeQyQKptRc**

If your using fortigate firewall as core or perimeter devices and Cisco SG300 as distribution switch in your setup then you can accomplish this task by creating sub interface on fortigate firewall

Configure SG300 switch to Fortigate firewall with trunk link allowing all vlans

And configuration public ip of isp on outside interface of fortigate and configure default route in fortinet firewall pointing towards isp gateway

And now in SG300 switch create all vlans which were created in fortigate subinterface . Now create access ports in SG300 switch for desktops ,and server connetivity.

Then after create outbound policy in perimeter firewall for internet access

`source interface : Lan destination interface : Outside facing interface source address : LAN POOL NETWORK Destination address : ANY servies: ports allowed as per your requirements action : ALLOWED Security profiles: ON`

Then create inbound policy in firewall if your are having application hosted in your local lan and wants to access from internet

`Creaat VIP object as Publi ip mapping with " Object name " WEB SERVER = Publicip mapped with application hosted private ip`

**inbound policy**

`source interface : outside interface destination interface : LAN SOURCE ADDRESS : any destination address : WEB SERVER /*As per vip created above */ services : as per application requirement mostly "https" security profiles : on action : allowed`

**Create implicit deny policy at bottom \ *this policy is used to deny non matching traffic and to monitoring unwanted traffic on firewall**

`Source interface : any destination interface :ANY Source address : any destination address : any services ports : any action : deny`

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Please consider adding more details so this answer remains useful even after the linked video is removed.

Comment: Thank you, you helped to clarify the issue. It was a static route problem, but still it was pretty important to configure the ipv4 policies.